# Java распарсить данные сайта

Tags: java, веб-программирование

Как получить данные со страницы сайта?

Например, есть сайт lumosity.com. Как с помощью *java* пройти авторизацию и получить информацию с заданной страницы?

Comment: Например, с помощью Jsoup.

Answer (score 1):

Пример использования библиотеки jsoup https://github.com/Medniy2000/jobfinder